# Third intro slide causes crash

Tags: java, android

I wanted to create an Intro slider in my app, everything works fine but when I want to go to my third slide, the app crashes. The first and second slides work well but the third slider causes a crash.

I tried a lot of different solutions but none of them work. The debugger says that there is something wrong with my dots array, but I don't know why.

Here is my welcome activity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdpter;
    private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
    private TextView[] dots;
    private int[] layouts;
    private Button btnSkip , btnNext;
    private PrefManager prefManager;

    protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );


        prefManager = new PrefManager ( this );
        if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch ( true )){
            launchLOGinScreen();
            finish ();
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=21){
            getWindow ().getDecorView ().setSystemUiVisibility ( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setContentView ( R.layout.welcome_activity );

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
        btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

        layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.intro_slider_one,
                R.layout.intro_slider_two,
                R.layout.intro_slider_three
        };
        addBottomDots(0);

        changeStatusBarColor();

        myViewPagerAdpter = new MyViewPagerAdapter ();
        viewPager.setAdapter ( myViewPagerAdpter );
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener ( viewPagerPageChangeListener );

        btnSkip.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                launchLOGinScreen();
            }
        } );
        btnNext.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int current = getItem(+1);
                if (current<layouts.length){
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem ( current );
                }else {
                    launchLOGinScreen();
                }
            }
        } );
    }
    private void addBottomDots(int currentPage){
        dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

        int[] colorsActive = getResources ().getIntArray ( R.array.array_dot_active );
        int[] colorsInactive = getResources ().getIntArray ( R.array.array_dot_inactive );

        dotsLayout.removeAllViews ();
        for (int i = 0;i<dots.length;i++){
            dots[i] = new TextView ( this );
            dots[i].setText ( Html.fromHtml ( "?" ) );
            dots[i].setTextSize ( 35 );
            dots[i].setTextColor ( colorsInactive[currentPage] );
            dotsLayout.addView ( dots[i] );
        }
        if (dots.length>0)
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor ( colorsActive[currentPage] );
    }
    private int getItem(int i){
        return viewPager.getCurrentItem ()+i;
    }

    private void launchLOGinScreen(){
        prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
        startActivity ( new Intent ( WelcomeActivity.this,sign_up_and_sign_in.class) );
        finish ();
    }
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener () {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {


            addBottomDots ( position );
            if (position == layouts.length - 1){
                btnNext.setText( getString ( R.string.btn_next ));
                btnSkip.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    };
    private void changeStatusBarColor(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            Window window = getWindow ();
            window.addFlags ( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS );
            window.setStatusBarColor ( Color.TRANSPARENT );
        }
    }
    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyViewPagerAdapter(){

        }
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container , int position){
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService ( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate ( layouts[position] , container,false );
            container.addView ( view );
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return layouts.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView ( view );
        }
    }
}
```

I want all three slides to work and not cause crashes.

Comment: "The debugger says that there is something wrong with my dots array". Please post this error log.

Comment: Post the crash stacktrace.

Comment: add Logcat messages